# Angular 2: How can I use the same component on a page with different html element ids?

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a component that uses bootstrap's panel to display some data.

I made the panel collapsible using the data-toggle attribute.

`panel.component.html`

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading clickable" href="#panel" data-toggle="collapse">
    <h4 class="panel-title">{{title}}</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="panel" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <!-- Some data here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to use this component twice on the same page

```
<app-panel [title]="title 1" [data]="data1"></app-panel>
<app-panel [title]="title 2" [data]="data2"></app-panel>
```

Pressing the header of the top panel, collapses the body of the top panel (as it should).

The problem is that when I press the header of the bottom panel, it collapses the body of the top panel.

After inspecting the elements in the browser I noticed that it's because they're using the same id's (`id="panel"`).

I know that it can be fixed by using the ng2-bootstrap module for example, but I prefer to fix it without adding additional 3rd party modules to my project.

So how can I use the same component more than once on the same page without the id attributes interrupting each other?

Comment: What about setting the `id` explicitely like `<app-panel id="a" [title]="title 1" [data]="data1"></app-panel>`?

Comment: I think you want to change your template html so that you bind your id and href attributes to something you set in your component.  You can't , really shouldn't, have multiple instances of same id in the DOM, as the html is then invalid.

Comment: @123 did my answer works for you?

Comment: @OctavioGarbarino Passing the id as an input would work, but I guess that using some randomly generated id would be better so I wouldn't need to worry about it at all. Is there anything built-in in angular2 that can do that?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to pass the id as a parameter like you have passed the title and data. You can use the same method to pass the id to use, and use a default id if none is specified.

In panel.component.ts you could have something like:

```
@Input()
id: String = "panel";
```